# How to override resourses for setContenView

Tags: android, android-activity

I made this class extends Resourses:

```
public class CustomResources extends Resources {

    private static CustomResources instance;

    /**
     * Create a new Resources object on top of an existing set of assets in an
     * AssetManager.
     *
     * @param assets  Previously created AssetManager.
     * @param metrics Current display metrics to consider when
     *                selecting/computing resource values.
     * @param config  Desired device configuration to consider when
     */
    public CustomResources(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config) {
        super(assets, metrics, config);
    }

    public static CustomResources getInstance(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CustomResources(assets, metrics, config);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        return super.getString(id) + " $$";
    }
}
```

I set new resourse thru:

```
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    return CustomResources.getInstance(super.getAssets(), super.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), super.getResources().getConfiguration());
}
```

So, I wan't custom resurses works for all strings that included in layout which i load by:

```
setContentView(R.layout.at_site);
```

But it works only for strings loaded by:

```
title.setText(getString(R.string.at_site_at_receiver));
```

What did i missed?

Comment: You can't do this like this. Android accesses the resources in many places where you have no chance to use your overriding class. What exactly are you trying to do? Surely there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am trying to make several variants of labels for my widgets in activity and switch between them depending on an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use Android's built-in alternative resource management (see [Guide to Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

If that doesn't fit with your needs then I suggest you declare all resources as arrays, and for each resource, choose the appropriate one depending on the user's setting. But this will be a much more complicated solution.